# Preventing code deletion in a p2p app

Tags: p2p, bitcoin, dht

user A and user B download an open source app built on a DHT. The app generates a bitcoin keypair for each user. The app demands that if user A requests user B's data, user A has to pay user B a small micropayment. A problem arises if the app is open source and p2p -- user A can simply remove the snippet of code requiring him to pay user B before requesting user B's data.

Any thoughts on a solution that would force user A to pay user B for their data?

Answer (score 0):

> A problem arises if the app is open source and p2p -- user A can simply remove the snippet of code requiring him to pay user B before requesting user B's data.

The specific problem you state only arises because B does not trust A.

Since you do not state that there is any problem with A trusting B the answer can be as trivial as *B withholds the data until A's payment has arrived*.

If neither party trusts the other you would need something consisting of [several layered zero knowledge proofs and locked bitcoin transactions](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Zero_Knowledge_Contingent_Payment).

A slightly less heavyweight approach would be using a [trusted 3rd party for escrow](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Contracts#Example_2%3A_Escrow_and_dispute_mediation) or A committing their payment first, B sending the data and then A and B agreeing on successful delivery, with the risk of leaving the coins stranded if A defects after delivery.

You probably should ask further questions on http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com